# How to stretch the text horizontally like we stretch an image horizontally or vertically in pdfmake or change the width of text

Tags: text, width, pdfmake, stretch

I'm using pdfmake tool. I am stuck at a place where I need to stretch the text horizontally or change the width of the text

```
 "columns": [
    {
      "text": [
        {
          "text": "Authorization Form for Release of Information from Other Members",
          "font": "Arial",
          "fontSize": 17,
          "bold": true,
          "decoration"
        }
      ],
      "style": "title",
      "alignment": "center",
      "width": 435,
      "margin": [60,0,0,0]
    }
```

]

Note: The width property which is being used is changing the width of the column which dosen't affecting the text size

I have tried the properties like textHeight, textWidth & assigned the property width, height directly to the text {} block